# How to remove redundant vertices from a graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to generate tree-level graphs (no cycles or loops) with 3-point vertices only starting from a single vertex graph. I'm defining

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := 
     {a -> Subscript[v, a], b -> Subscript[v, a], c <-> Subscript[v, a]}
```

then `Graph[f[1, 2, 3], VertexLabels -> "Name"]` generates

[image]

but when I try

```
Graph[Join @@ {f[1, 2, a], f[3, 4, a]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

I get

[image]

with the vertex `a` being what I call redundant, and similarly by joining more graphs. The Join part contains

```
a <-> Subscript[v, 1], a <-> Subscript[v, 3]
```

so I'd need to replace this with `Subscript[v, 1] <-> Subscript[v, 3]`.

I want to know how to do this for any number of joined graphs, e.g.

```
Join @@ {f[1, 2, a], f[3, a, b], f[4, b, c], f[5, 6, c]}
```

and so on.

### Update

As suggested in the comments, `VertexContract[]` is meant to do the job, but it does not work for me (Mathematica 10) when using subscripts; I'm using this notation because it promise to be helpful when trying to generalize. I found a workaround that also does the trick with `SimpleGraph` and `VertexReplace`, e.g. for the second case in my original question:

```
SimpleGraph[VertexReplace[Join @@ {f[1, 2, a], f[3, 4, a]}, 
 a -> Subscript[v, 1]], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

but then I'd need a way to go through the edges with redundant vertices to know what vertex replacements should be done!

Comment: Have you seen `VertexContract[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, that does the trick, although it seems to be in conflict with the subscript notation for the vertices

Comment: @Kuba By tree-level I meant with no cycles or loops, I'll specify in the question.

Comment: @CalGibson Ah, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := {
  DirectedEdge[a, Subscript[v, a]],
  DirectedEdge[b, Subscript[v, a]],
  UndirectedEdge[c, Subscript[v, a]]}

edges = Join[f[1, 2, a], f[3, a, b], f[4, b, c], f[5, 6, c]];

graph = Graph[edges,
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Starting graph]

Vertex pairs to connect (brute force):

```
connect = Cases[
  Subsets[VertexList[graph], {2}], {u_, v_} /;
   Module[{
     p = FindShortestPath[graph, u, v],
     r = FindShortestPath[graph, v, u]},
    Or[
     Length[p] == 3 && VertexDegree[graph, p[[2]]] == 2,
     Length[r] == 3 && VertexDegree[graph, r[[2]]] == 2]]];

(* {{Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 3]}, 
    {Subscript[v, 3], Subscript[v, 4]},
    {Subscript[v, 4], Subscript[v, 5]}} *)
```

Vertices to remove:

```
remove = FindShortestPath[graph, ##][[2]] & @@@ connect;

(* {a, b, c} *)

EdgeAdd[graph, UndirectedEdge @@@ connect]~VertexDelete~remove
```

[image]

## Update: speed-up

Finding connecting pairs doesn't scale well. Better check only particular pairs, those with graph distance two, instead of all. So you can replace that `Subset` expression with `list`.

```
dm = GraphDistanceMatrix[graph];

list = Map[
   VertexList[graph][[#]] &,
   Position[UpperTriangularize@dm, 2]];
```

Comment: I tried with
`f[1, 2, a], f[3, a, b], f[b, c, e], f[6, c, d], f[4, 5, d], f[7, e, g], f[8, 9, g]`
but it misses one vertex; the reason seems to be that it connects to the other two through both directed edges.

Comment: @CalGibson Why do you say the procedure misses it? It seems that `c` is not redundant here.

Comment: The edges contain `c -> Subscript[v, 6], c -> Subscript[v, b]`, so I'd need this to be replaced with `Subscript[v, 6] <-> Subscript[v, b]`, which it does not seem to do (Directed or Undirected is ultimately irrelevant, I just need at least one internal edge -I think- to be Undirected so that the graph looks like a Feynman diagram)

Comment: @CalGibson Can edges produced by `f` be all of `UndirectedEdge`? This would of course help remove `c`.

Comment: No, I need the vertices with numbers to be connected through directed edges

Comment: @CalGibson Modify `f` so it produces only undirected edges. Successfully remove the redundant vertices. Now make a new graph with certain edges refashioned, e.g. `UndirectedEdge[a_Integer, b_Subscript] :> DirectedEdge[a, b]`.